# Why don't I end up with the same splitting field?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I've understood that the splitting field of $x^4+2$ and the splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$  are both the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2} , i)$. With degree $8$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This makes me wonder about the splitting field $F$ of $f(x)=x^8-4=(x^4+2)(x^4-2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The roots of $x^8-4$ are $\sqrt[4]{2}w$, where $w$ is an eight root of unity implying that $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2} , w)$. On the other hand since both of the irreducible factors of $f(x)$ splits over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2} , i)$ this should be the splitting field. The polynomial $x^4-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, which gives $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ and the polynomial $x^4+1$ satisfying $w$ seems to be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ but this would imply that $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=16$. A contradiction. Where is the argument wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})[x]$.

Comment: Wei then it all makes sense! I started to go bananas on the theory not keeping together. Another question, or two actually, if you don't mind, I wonder if the splitting field of $x^n-a$ always equal to the splitting field of $x^n+a$? And furthermore if $a$ would be another number say gcd(2,n)=1 would the $nth$ Cyclotomic polynomial then be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a})$? What is the relationship?